# .NET Remove empty tags from requests, proxy generated via WSDL

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wsdl

I'm working with an external partner who has provided a WSDL.  I've generated a proxy which is fine, except the partner is asking us to remove any tags with empty values.  It seems to me that the right place to accomplish this is for the partner to modify the WSDL to meet their requirements, but is there an easy way to remove empty tags in the generated proxy code?  ie: an event where we can modify the serialized XML before it is transmitted?  Thank you.

Comment: are your trying to use ``XDocument``,to parse and delete the empty tags from the ``xml``